# calling a class shared function from action

Tags: ios, swift

I have a file called SocialLogin.swift inside that I have a class with some functions see below.
What I am trying to do however is have the FirstViewController.swift set up a button which has an action.

The "action" is to call SocialLogin.shared.checkLogin() However everytime I run it seems to crash giving me no real understanding on why it does this.

Where when I run the same code but instead of sending it to a shared class, i send it to a local function it works fine.

```
 let buttonIcon = UIImage(systemName: "person.circle")

 let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Person", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(SocialLogin.shared.checkLogin(_:)))
         rightBarButton.image = buttonIcon

self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

This is the SocialLogin.swift file

```
class SocialLogin {
    static let shared = SocialLogin()

    @objc func checkLogin(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem!){
        print("checking now")
    }

    @objc func loginFacebook(){
        print("test")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try without sending param block

let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Person", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: SocialLogin.shared, action: #selector(SocialLogin().checkLogin(_:)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set proper target!

```
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Person", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: SocialLogin.shared, action: #selector(SocialLogin.checkLogin(_:)))
```

Comment: Don't I need to access the selector as #selector(SocialLogin.shared.checkLogin(_:)) ?